# Hosting sites from dropbox

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php, chdropboxsync

I know there are some great sites like site44.com, kissr which allows to host the site from the dropbox.

Well in my case, I don't want to use site 44 or kissr to host my site from dropbox. Is there a any API or some sort of tool that will allow me to connect my site and the dropbox ?.

I have a site where I need to make a client and at the time of creating a client, I need to create individual folder designated to each client. Of course, I am able to do that with HTML form and PHP. But now, what I am planning is, to create a folder and save some file in it in dropbox and eventually syncing those newly created folder in my site...

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how Site44 works, which is to poll the `/delta` API: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/23/using-dropboxs-delta-api-lessons-learned-from-site44

Instead of doing that, you could fetch data on-demand. So your website code could read files from Dropbox only when they're requested, which would save you the difficulty of polling `/delta` and keeping a local copy up-to-date.